# Executing a file in a network folder using batch

Tags: batch-file, networking

I would like to execute a .exe file located in one of our network drives. The code I currently have only opens up the network drive folder I call however it doesn't execute the program it just opens up the Parent folder (IT).

""Start T: \10.0.1.4\IT\Browser\ChromeSetup.exe""

Comment: `start "Window Title" "T:\…\ChromeSetup.exe"` (`Window Title` may even be an empty string but it must be present; otherwise, your quoted path is misinterpreted as the window title)

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm still getting the same results however.

'Start "" T: \\10.0.1.4\IT\Browser\ChromeSetup.exe'

Comment: Okay, going back and working with the script I got it to open up the Browser folder using this script `Start "" T:\Browser "ChromeSetup.exe"` now its the matter of getting it to run the application called.

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I found out that this code executed perfectly. It was the matter of putting the path in quotations. Feel silly missing that. Thanks to those who contributed.
`Start "" "T:\Browser\ChromeSetup.exe"`